# How to translate a Decision Tree in Orange to rules and print out the rules?

Tags: python, tree, rule, orange

I am wondering if anyone knows how to translate a Decision Tree in Orange to rules and print out the rules. The Orange Classification Trees document only shows how to print out a tree. A sample code to do this is greatly helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.classification.tree.html.

This is for Orange 2. Orange 3 cannot yet print the trees in the same way since it currently relies on sklearn's trees. Printing like in Orange 2 will be supported when we replace them with a better implementation.

Comment: Has there been any update since your reply. Can I convert the Tree from Orange 3 to rules or a function?